# Output of LM35 temperature sensor > 3.3 V?

Tags: sensor, temperature, lm35

According to the datasheet the maximum rating of the output of an LM35 is 6 V.

However, the output should give 10 mV/C and it supports upto 150 C, which results in 10 mV/C * 150 C = 1500 mV which is 1.5 V. In what cases it will deliver more than 1.5 V?

**Update**

I initially added a statement that the output should not be connected to a 3.3 V ADC. However, it seems this is not the case, still my question stays, how can the output be 6 V?

Excerpt from [LM35 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Yes, we need to see the context of the warning that you mention. Please provide a link to the source of those statements.

Comment: The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) says that its operating range is 4-30 V.

Comment: @CL. / Elliot Alderson ... I misread it, it was about the input voltage, and also the voltage dividers where not specifically for the LM35. However, still my question exists why I can get 6V? It will ruin my STM32 ADC which can handle only 3.3V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output voltage as a function of temperature is **with respect to the GND pin** of the sensor. This voltage cannot exceed 1.5V in normal operation.

The maximum output voltage spec of -1V to 6V is **with respect to circuit ground**. The GND pin of the sensor is lifted above circuit ground in certain applications, such as to convert the sensor output voltage to a voltage proportional to Fahrenheit temperature. Take a look at the system examples given in the data sheet. The example circuit shown below is an example from the [linked data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Is this voltage lift also applicable for negative values?

Comment: I was curious to see the Celcius to Fahrenheit converter using electronic components, that's pretty amusing. (I also added it to the answer, hope you dont mind).

Comment: Don't use an image unless you make it very clear where you got the image. I added a sentence to clarify that.

Comment: I added a new question about the diodes related to the system applications you refer at: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/421011/why-there-are-two-diodes-instead-of-one-used-for-an-lm35-negative-temperature-ci

Comment: What does circuit ground have to do with anything if the circuit ground isn't actually connected to the device anywhere? I don't follow how some arbitrary reference voltage relates to the absolute maximum ratings of the device. Surely only the currents and voltages inside the device itself can damage it?